# Mediaplayer fails to open parsed URI

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Trying to open a file using Uri.parse, but I keep getting denied access to it. I'm very puzzled of what is wrong.

The `Manifest.xml` cropped for readability

```
<application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</application>
```

The code snippet causing the error:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               .getAbsolutePath()+"/victamjpeg.sdp");

videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

And the actual error:

> 10-30 01:11:38.640 4293-4293/? W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/1A0C-331C/victamjpeg.sdp
>
> 10-30 01:11:38.640 4293-4293/? W/VideoView: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1A0C-331C/victamjpeg.sdp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>
> 10-30 01:11:38.640 4293-4293/? W/VideoView:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>   10-30 01:11:38.640 4293-4293/? W/VideoView:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)

It looks like I don't have the permissions to read it, but I have to my knowledge set that permission. Doing an `ls -l` from `adb shell` proves that the file is at `/sdcard/victamjpeg.sdp` and owned by root.

Comment: remove "/" this or change to "\"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it appears that your `<uses-permission>` elements are in the wrong place. They need to be children of `<manifest>`, peers of `<application>`. What you have shows them as children of `<application>`.

Second, replace:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/victamjpeg.sdp");
```

with:

```
Uri video = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "victamjpeg.sdp"));
```

This handles that case where `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a value with a trailing `/`. It also puts the scheme in the `Uri`, which your implementation does not, resulting in a universally invalid `Uri`.

Also note that if you are testing on Android 6.0 that the storage permissions are `dangerous`, and you will need to use [the runtime permission system](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html) if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher.

Comment: Thanks @Commonsware King of SO. ;) When I fixed the silly bugs I had and rolled back to API level 22 it worked. Was running API 23 w/o thinking that the permissions had changed.

Answer (score 3):

The uses-permission tags need to be outside the application tag.